# how to find value of a non-blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have sheet of data in excel. In column BF, when I select the BF1 to BF7 it shows there are 3 counts however, I failed to determine what that value is or why excel is counting a seemingly blank cell, BF3. I tried to change color of font of cell BF3, and I used 2 formulas to test it, still I can't figure out what the cell value is.

First formula I used `=isblank(BF3)` and second formula I used `=value(BF3)` and still no luck. Clearly the cell is not blank but what is it ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `=BF3=""`.  Blank and "" are not the same thing,  Neither is " ".

Comment: Thanks for the information, the result is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BF3),"Truly empty",IF(LEN(BF3)=0,"Null value","Character code: " & CODE(BF3)))
```

where `Null value` means that **BF3** contains something like:

```
=""
```

or its equivalent.

*(An alternative:)*

```
=IF(ISBLANK(BF3),"Truly empty",IF(LEN(BF3)=0,"Null value","Character code: " & UNICODE(BF3)))
```

If it is some weird Unicode character.

Comment: @s a ***32*** is a space character.

Comment: So basically it is not like a "value" where we can use for data analysis purposes. Got it. Thank you for explaining.